# Show error message on bad request with Angular HTTP

Tags: angular

I have a part of code on my services that check for a bad request in HTTP requests and send an alert on the user. Also, I have another message that raise if the request was succeed. However, my problem is that in case of an error, both messages are raised.

This is my service:

```
deleteProduct(product:Product) {
    if ( this._loggedInGuard.isLoggedIn() ) {
      let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
      let body = JSON.stringify(product);
      let headers = new Headers(
         { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "X-HTTP-Method-Override": "DELETE",
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token});
      return this._http
      .post(this.API + "/products/"+product.id, body, {headers: headers} )
      .map(res => res.json())
      .catch(this._responseService.catchBadResponse)
      .finally(() => this._responseService.success('Well done'));
    }  
  }
```

And this is my `ResponseService` code:

```
@Injectable()
export class ResponseService {

  constructor() { }

  catchBadResponse: (errorResponse: any) => Observable<any> = (errorResponse: any) => {
    let res = <Response>errorResponse;
    let err = res.json();
    let emsg = err ?
      (err.error ? err.error : JSON.stringify(err)) :
      (res.statusText || 'unknown error');
      Messenger().post( { message: emsg.message, hideAfter: 10, type: 'error', showCloseButton: false } );

    return Observable.of();
  }

  success(msg) {
    Messenger().post( { message: msg, hideAfter: 10, type: 'success', showCloseButton: false } );
  }
}
```

I guess I need to add an exception on `finally()` to be executed only if I don't have any error. But I am not able to make it work.

Comment: Close and negative vote without a comment? Can you please elaborate why this is off-topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Finally` is always called. Replace your `finally` with `do`. The do is not executed when a exception is catched